# Cut off tubeless plug head?

Tags: puncture, tubeless

I use tubeless tires ranging from 30 to 40mm in width. When I puncture and the sealant doesn't cut it, I plug the hole with a Dynaplug.

On longer rides, I carry a spare tube (or two) just in case. It occurs to me that a tube inserted into a tire that already has a Dynaplug in it will instantly puncture, since it essentially inflates directly into a spearhead. Hence when I get home after plugging my tire (or, at the latest, when inserting a tube by the roadside), should I cut off the plug head on the inside so it will take a tube, or will this compromise the seal?

Comment: Wait until you need to use a tube to cut off the Dynaplug heads? A box cutter blade does not take up much space in a tool kit.

Comment: Yeah, I'd cut off the head with a knife that you likely have, and maybe for extra security stick a tire boot or a dollar bill on the other side just to make sure the surface is good.

Comment: Thanks @ArgentiApparatus and @Batman; if either or both of you would like to formulate your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept the one that works best for me. It would also be great if you could include in your answer whether you've done this yourself.

Comment: A potential problem might be that the 'head' is the only thing keeping the plug in place, and once cut off, the repair might not be strong enough to stop the tube blowing out of the hole.  Batman's idea of booting the area to be safe seems a good call.

Comment: A point of info: there are tubeless plugs that don’t have metal tips. For example, Stan’s plugs are just a ‘bacon strip’ of rubber (or whatever material that is). You could switch to those. That said, I am under the impression that Dynaplugs work very well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should definitely cut the head out when you get back to your house, and then patch the tire.   Whether you want to install a tube, instead of continuing to run tubeless.

Comment: Neither can I. FWIW, my impression is that if you are ok to just ride a tubeless tire with one or more tubeless plugs still in it. If you decided to run it tubed instead, then I am not sure you need to patch the tire (unless it got slashed, in which case I suppose you boot it).

Comment: @WeiwenNg I agree. Plugs are pretty much permanent if in they are holding air. I've had to resort to a tube with a tire that had previously installed plugs. Prior to installing the tube, I booted the slash that necessitated the tube and pulled all of plugs from punctures out.